# String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated. Column the right size?

Tags: c#, sql

Hi i have been working on a table for a while now and it seemed to be working. I am passing a claim number then going through on a separate connection and adding to that claimnum row. i Only have this one value being passed so i know this is the value and column in question. the number it is passing as a string is 6450202115. 
the code is :

```cs
 SqlConnection conn1 = null;

conn1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=sql-4;Initial Catalog=HIIGLargeLoss;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework");
conn1.Open();
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("IF NOT EXISTS(Select claimnum From HIIGLOSS WHERE claimnum = @claimnum) INSERT INTO HIIGLOSS (claimnum) VALUES (@claimnum)", conn1);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@claimnum", Holding_Values.claim_Num);
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn1.Close();
```

The value of the column is:

[image]

I have tried making the length longer with no success. If any tips or idea what is going on please let me know!
Thank you!

Comment: Check the length of `Holding_Values.claim_Num.Length` what do you see?

Comment: I wonder if the problem is that you're not actually telling SQL what the parameter type is, so it's thinking it's an int, but that value is too large for an int. You could try `var parameter = cmd1.Parameters.Add("@claimnum", SqlDbType.VarChar);
parameter.Value = Holding_Values.claim_Num`;

Comment: AddWithValue may be messing up your data: [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @vendettamit i am getting 10 when i get the length should nvarchar(50) cover that?

Comment: @stuartd When i try doing this i still get the same error

Comment: @AndrewMorton tried using `cmd1.Parameters.Add("@claimnum", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Holding_Values.claim_Num;` and am still getting the same error.

Comment: @PhDDenseOne You have to specify the length of the string otherwise it assumes 1. I happen to prefer the really explicit way of specifying the parameters, e.g. `cmd1.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@claimnum", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, .Size = 50, .Value = Holding_Values.claim_Num})`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton its good to know this in the future! one of the other columns wasn't the right size so i fixed it thanks for the help!

Comment: @stuartd thanks for the help!

Comment: @vendettamit thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help I've learned a lot from looking into this. Another column was the issue (not the right size duh) and for some reason the error popped up even the it wasn't involved with the column in question. Trying all of your suggestions was able to help me find this mistake so i appreciate the help!